# error al enviar datos de AngularJS(Angular1) a php

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Tengo un extraño problema al enviar datos a php con AngularJS, tengo que enviar dos Strings y un array con datos, los String llegan correctamente a php pero el array llega vacio(aunqe aparece como array).
Hago un console.log() justo antes de la peticion y todo esta correcto, sin embargo al llegar a php haciendo un var_dump() el array aparece vacio.
Pero lo mas extraño de todo es que en este programa hago otra peticion casi igual a php y si envargo esta otra funciona correctamente.

esta es la llamada:

```
$scope.modificarD = function() {
    $scope.datosM = [];
    $scope.datosM = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos);
    $scope.datosM.id = angular.copy(parseInt($scope.modal.datos.id));
    $scope.datosM.nombre = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.nombre);
    $scope.datosM.descripcion = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.descripcion);
    $scope.datosM.categoria = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.categoria);
    $scope.datosM.idTienda = null;
    $scope.datosM.arrayIma = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.arrayIma);
    $scope.datosM.stock = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.stock);
    $scope.datosM.precio = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.precio);
    $scope.datosM.estado = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.estado);
    auxF = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.fechaFinCampanha);
    fecha = auxF.getFullYear()+"-"+$scope.ceros(auxF.getMonth()+1)+"-"+$scope.ceros(auxF.getDate());
    $scope.datosM.fechaFinCampanha = fecha;

    console.log($scope.datosM);

    var peticion = {
    "url"    : "servidor/rutinas.php",
    "method" : "POST",
    "data"   : { opcion     : "producto",
                 accion     : "modif",
                 parametros : $scope.datosM 
               }
    };

    console.log(peticion);

    $http(peticion).then(function(bien){
    $scope.respuesta = angular.copy(bien.data);
        if($scope.respuesta.estado == undefined) {
            alert("Error desconocido");
        } else {
             if($scope.respuesta.estado == "ok") {              
                 $scope.datoss();
                 $scope.cerrarModal('#mymodal1');
                 $scope.muestraMens($scope.respuesta.mens); 
              } else {
                  $scope.cerrarModal('#mymodal1');
                  $scope.muestraMens($scope.respuesta.tipoError);
               }
         }
    },

    function(mal){
        $scope.muestraMens("Error en conexión");
    });
}

$scope.cerrarModal = function(referencia) {
    $(referencia).modal('close');
}
```

cabe destacar ademas que para pasar los datos de la modal intente primero hacer un `angular.copy()` pero nose porque en esa variable no funciona, por lo que tuve que ir metiendo uno por uno cada valor en el array

aqui podeis ver lo ponen los `console.log()`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el `var_dump` hecho desde php:

```
$recibido = file_get_contents('php://input');
$cliente = json_decode($recibido);
$dato1 = cliente->opcion;
$dato2 = cliente->accion;
$arrayR = cliente->parametros;

var_dump($cliente);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para terminar os muestro otra funcion que enviando casi lo mismo si funciona para que veais cual es la diferencia

```
$scope.nuevo = function() {
    $scope.datosP = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos);
    auxF = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.fechaFinCampanha);
    $scope.datosP.idTienda = $scope.idsTiendas[$scope.nombreTiendas[$scope.modal.datos.idTienda]];
    if($scope.productoElegido!=""){
        $scope.datosP["id"] = $scope.idsProds[$scope.productoElegido];
    } 

    if(auxF != null) {
        fecha = auxF.getFullYear()+"-"+$scope.ceros(auxF.getMonth()+1)+"-"+$scope.ceros(auxF.getDate());
        $scope.datosP.fechaFinCampanha = fecha;
    }

    var peticion = {
    "url"    : "servidor/rutinas.php",
    "method" : "POST",
    "data"   : { opcion     : "producto",
                 accion     : "anhadir",
                 parametros : $scope.datosP 
               }
    };

    $http(peticion).then(function(bien){
    $scope.respuesta = angular.copy(bien.data);
        if($scope.respuesta.estado == undefined) {
            alert("Error desconocido");
        } else {
             if($scope.respuesta.estado == "ok") {              
                 $scope.datoss();
                 $scope.cerrarModal('#mymodal1');
                 $scope.muestraMens($scope.respuesta.mens); 
              } else {
                  $scope.cerrarModal('#mymodal1');
                  $scope.muestraMens($scope.respuesta.tipoError);
               }
         }
    },

    function(mal){
        $scope.muestraMens("Error en conexión");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno pues despues de muchas vueltas he logrado mandar los datos de una forma que funciona:

```
$scope.modificarArriba = function() {

    auxF = angular.copy($scope.modal.datos.fechaFinCampanha);
    fecha = auxF.getFullYear()+"-"+$scope.ceros(auxF.getMonth()+1)+"-"+$scope.ceros(auxF.getDate());

    var peticion = {
    "url"    : "servidor/rutinas.php",
    "method" : "POST",
    "data"   : { opcion     : "producto",
                 accion     : "modif",
                 parametros : { id : parseInt($scope.modal.datos.id),
                                nombre : $scope.modal.datos.nombre,
                                descripcion : $scope.modal.datos.descripcion,
                                categoria : $scope.modal.datos.categoria,
                                fechaFinCampanha : fecha,
                                idTienda : null,
                                arrayIma : $scope.modal.datos.arrayIma,
                                stock : $scope.modal.datos.stock,
                                precio : $scope.modal.datos.precio,
                                estado : $scope.modal.datos.estado
                              }
               }
    };

    $http(peticion).then(function(bien){
    $scope.respuesta = angular.copy(bien.data);
        if($scope.respuesta.estado == undefined) {
            alert("Error desconocido");
        } else {
             if($scope.respuesta.estado == "ok") {              
                 $scope.datoss();
                 $scope.cerrarModal('#mymodal1');
                 $scope.muestraMens($scope.respuesta.mens); 
              } else {
                  $scope.cerrarModal('#mymodal1');
                  $scope.muestraMens($scope.respuesta.tipoError);
               }
         }
    },

    function(mal){
        $scope.muestraMens("Error en conexión");
    });
}
```

Al mandar los parametros creando el array dentro de la propia variable de llamada si funciona, aun cuando uno de esos parametros es otro array